# after_update callback causing never ending loop in a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, crop, auto-update

My model's `cropping` method is called in a loop which never ends after I update the attributes of user in the controller.

`User controller code`-

```
   def change_img  
      @user = current_user

      #this triggers the model's after_update callback
      @user.update_attributes(params[:user])  

      flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated Image."  
      render :action => 'crop'  
   end
```

`User Model code`-

```
after_update :reprocess_avatar, :if => :cropping? 


  def cropping?  
   #this method is called infinitely why?

  !crop_x.blank? && !crop_y.blank? && !crop_w.blank? && !crop_h.blank? 

  end
```

Once the crop_x, crop_y, crop_w and crop_h are set, the `cropping` method will always return true which will keep on calling the `reprocess_avatar` method. This is probably due to the fact that `reprocess_avatar` method is also updating `avatar` attribute of user table. And so again `after_update` triggers causing a loop.

Is there any way to call the method only once after update?

Comment: Just set the crop_x value to blank at the end of your after_update function.

Comment: @khustochka - I updated the question that `reprocess_avatar` method is causing the update which in turn calling after_update hooks again and again.

Comment: @khustochka- yes that is what happening here.

Comment: sorry, i missed it. I guess the best solution is to refactor it somehow. Or inside `reprocess_avatar` you can use methods that skip callbacks: [Skipping callbacks](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations_callbacks.html#skipping-callbacks)

Comment: @LastCoder - It will not resolve the purpose as I can't set it to blank because the `reprocess_avatar` needs the crop_x value for it to process first.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I resolved the issue by removing the `after_update` from model and making a call from controller's function itself.

```
   def change_img  
      @user = current_user         
      @user.update_attributes(params[:user]) 

      if(!@user.crop_x.blank? && !@user.crop_y.blank? && 
     !@user.crop_w.blank? &&  !@user.crop_h.blank?)
         @user.avatar.reprocess! 
      end

      flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated Image."  
      render :action => 'crop'  
   end
```

Thanks!

Comment: I am facing the same issue asked above, then your answer fixed that issue, but the line @user.avatar.reprocess! giving me a error undefined method `avatar_crop_x' . Can you suggest me anything or I need to open new thread for this. I am using rails 4.1.

Answer (score 0):

if the reprocess_avatar is updating something, make sure you are using any non-callback update method so you don't trigger any further callbacks in the object. If, for instance, you are settings flags or updating some id column or setting timestamps on your DB representation, use some straight-to-db method like #update_column or #touch. But without seeing what your reprocess_avatar method actually makes it hard to give a better advice.

Comment: I am using the avatar cropping example code from the asciicasts - http://asciicasts.com/episodes/182-cropping-images

Comment: I used `User.skip_callback(:update, :after, :reprocess_avatar)` in cropper.rb but that skipped the image cropping too. :(